# vscode - C/C++ debug console - how to compare pointer variable?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-code, null

In Vscode - Debug console, how do I compare if a pointer variable equal to NULL pointer?

sample code:

```
void * my_malloc(size_t Size) {
    void *p;
    if (!(p = malloc(Size))) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory with my_malloc.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}
```

During debug, I typed `p == NULL` and received `-var-create: unable to create variable object`.

However, if I do `1 == 2` or `1 == 1`, I'll get `0` or `1` as response respectively; so I know simple comparison like that in debug console works.

But why can't I compare pointer with NULL pointer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the VS Code debugger, but it could be because `NULL` is a macro, so it's not known at runtime. Try `p == 0`... or simply use `p` and compare using your eyes.

Comment: This response means that your variable was not visible at that point. It could be optimized out or out of scope

Comment: You guys are correct. NULL is #define NULL ((void *) 0)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `NULL` is `#define NULL ((void *) 0)`; at run time, `NULL` no longer exists.
So the solution is to compare `p == (void *) 0`, and I will get the answer needed.